# Import pandas dataframe column as string not int or float

Tags: python, pandas

I was referring to this question.

```
ID
00013007854817840016671868
00013007854817840016749251
00013007854817840016754630
00013007854817840016781876
00013007854817840017028824
00013007854817840017963235
00013007854817840018860166


df = read_csv('sample.csv')

df.ID
>>

0   -9223372036854775808
1   -9223372036854775808
2   -9223372036854775808
3   -9223372036854775808
4   -9223372036854775808
5   -9223372036854775808
6   -9223372036854775808
Name: ID
```

The proposed solution is such that:

```
read_csv('sample.csv', dtype={'ID': object})
```

However, what if I want the whole `csv` file to be read as `str` columns instead of `int`?. It would be extremely taxing to have a dictionary for each column. Is there any cleaner method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use parameter `dtype` with `str`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', dtype=str)
```